PSPDFKit in Typescript in React JS
I'm using this library to draw rectangle on PDF and created POC successfully but now I want to integrate it in my real time project which is in React JS and Typescript
https://pspdfkit.com/getting-started/web/?frontend=vanillajs&download=npm&integration=module
and I'm getting this error while integrating


so my question is it available for typescript or not because as per my search I didn't find typescript version anymore? Please any help is appreciated.

Here I've found solution for this issue that we need to run this command
cp -R ./node_modules/pspdfkit/dist/pspdfkit-lib public/pspdfkit-lib
so it'll create pspdfkit-lib folder in public directory and our code will detect that and provide necessary dependencies.
